# How to update document data in nested object in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

This is default schema model :-

```
const UserSettings = new Schema({
      ID: {  type: Number,  required: true, exists: false, unique : true },
      UserID : Number,
      Account : {
          Name : String,
          Email : {  type: String,  required: "email id is required", exists: false, unique : true },
          UserName : String,
          isFacebook :  {type : Boolean, default : false}
      },
      Notification : {
                  Trending : {
                      isEmail : {type : Boolean, default : true},
                      isPush :  {type : Boolean, default : true},
                      Button : {
                        isDaily :  {type : Boolean, default : false},
                        isWeekly :  {type : Boolean, default : false},
                        isOff : {type : Boolean, default : false}
                      }
                  },
                  Recommanded : {
                      isEmail : {type : Boolean, default : true},
                      isPush :  {type : Boolean, default : true},
                      Button : {
                        isDaily :  {type : Boolean, default : false},
                        isWeekly :  {type : Boolean, default : false},
                        isOff : {type : Boolean, default : false}
                      }
                  }
       }
});
```

When I save values it will enter the default fields values in schema,

```
    "Account" : {
    "Email" : "ted@gmail.com",
    "isFacebook" : true,
    "Name" : "ted"
},
"Notification" : {
    "Trending" : {
        "Button" : {
            "isDaily" : false,
            "isWeekly" : false,
            "isOff" : false
        },
        "isEmail" : true,
        "isPush" : true
    },
    "Recommanded" : {
        "Button" : {
            "isDaily" : false,
            "isWeekly" : false,
            "isOff" : false
        },
        "isEmail" : true,
        "isPush" : true
    }
}
```

In update case I have to passed selected arguments like only need to Update

```
Account{
Email : "ted1@gmail.com"
},
Notification {
  Trending {
      isPush : false,
  }    
}
```

Then how would I used mongo update query?

I have tried this solutions to update value but it will removed existing value :-

```
  return UserSettings.updateOne(
       {$and: [{  UserID: args.UserID },{ Status : 1 }]},
        { $push : { "Account":  args.Account  }},
       {
         upsert: true,
         returnNewDocument: true
       },
    );
```

and one more this :-

```
return UserSettings.updateOne(
       {$and: [{  UserID: args.UserID },{ Status : 1 }]},
       args,
       {
         upsert: true,
         returnNewDocument: true
       },
    );
```

Comment: Please upload your code from model file

Comment: You want unique email inside Account object?

Comment: yes, @Mr.Gandhi email validation is default handle by graphql, I have issue with nested data update

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let Account = args.Account
let condition = { $and: [ {  UserID: args.UserID },{ Status : 1 }]}, { 'Account.Email': args.Account.Email }] }; // here check email in sub document
UserSettings.updateOne(condition, { $set: { Account: Account } }).exec((err, data) => {
    if (err || data.nModified == 0) {
        UserSettings.updateOne({ UserID: args.UserID  }, { $push: { Account: Account } }).exec((err, data) => {
             return {'message':'Updated successfully','data':data}; // Send proper response as per your need
        });
    }
    else {
             return {'message':'Failed'};// Send proper response as per your need
    }
});
```

Comment: existing value gets removed, I want to update old values if field exists and if field not in array then need to push

Comment: err { MongoError: The field 'Account' must be an array but is of type object in document {_id: ObjectId('5dd52ff4701b262558ef9469')} this error is returned

Comment: You can do push operation only on array. So you will have change your model if want to do push operation

Comment: Right now it's object in your model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202871/discussion-between-addc-and-mr-gandhi).